# How to check the daily active users of each version

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have table1:

| server_time | ip | model | user_id | version | event_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-07-01 | 113 | A83 | u1 | v1 | login |
| 2018-07-01 | 114 | R11s | u2 | v2 | login |
| 2018-07-01 | 10 | R15 | u3 | v3 | login |
| 2018-07-02 | 211 | R11s | u2 | v4 | login |
| 2018-08-12 | 123 | R15 | u3 | v5 | login |

and table2:

| model | version |
| --- | --- |
| A83 | A |
| R11s | R |
| R15 | R |

I have 6 columns `server_time,ip,model,user_id,version,event_id` in table1 and 2 columns in table 2
How to check the daily active users of each version ,including dates when no records were generated into the table.

Comment: Show sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. Show desired output for this data as formatted table.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please define what you mean by "daily active users".

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive `CTE`, `CROSS JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` as follows:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select min(server_time) as dt, max(server_time) as max_dt from table1 t
    union all select dt + interval 1 day from cte t where dt < max_dt
)
select c.dt, m.version, count(distinct t.user_id) as cnt
  from cte c cross join table2 m
  left join table1 t on t.server_time = c.dt and c.model = m.model  
group by c.dt, m.version
```

There is `version` column in both the tables and I am considering that you want the `version` from `table2` for grouping.